# three.js - google map style zoom in/out and rotation around specific axis of tube geometry

Tags: google-maps, three.js

In a scene of `THREE.js` we can use different controls such as `THREE.TrackballControls`, `THREE.RollControls`. I've created a scene of 3d tube which is formed from 200 co-ordinates loaded as JSON data from external file. If I use `THREE.TrackballControls` I can rotate/spin the tube geometry but can not traverse the whole tube and If I use `THREE.RollControls` I can traverse the whole tube but can not spin/rotate properly. `THREE.RollControls` is not supported on Apple iPad.

I am developing this for Apple iPad.

Is there any way to implement google map type zoom in/out and rotation around specific axis functionality for a tube geometry ? Any tips or suggestions ?